# How to do compiletime checking of ByteArray lengths

Tags: toit

I want to make a check for the length of some constant ByteArrays that is part of a class. If the lengths of the ByteArrays are too big - I want to fail the check preferably at compile time. If that is not possible then I would like to somehow tell the user of my driver. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Toit doesn't have a way to specify the size of a `ByteArray` as part of its type. As such, there is no way to statically verify that users provide an array of the correct size.

Generally, you would check the size dynamically at runtime and throw if the object doesn't satisfy the requirements that were stated in the documentation (or that were implied). For example, here is a typical function of the core libraries:

```
  operator [..] --from=0 --to=size -> List:
    if not 0 <= from <= to <= size: throw "BAD ARGUMENTS"
    return ListSlice_ this from to
```

Checking the `from` and `to` isn't completely the same as checking the size of a byte-array, but it's not that far off either.

When `ByteArray`s need to be a specific size, they also often represent a certain structure. In that case you could either create a class with the corresponding fields (and then copy it into a byte-array yourself), or you could write a wrapper-class that allocates (or takes) a byte-array of the correct size. If it takes an array then you would still need to do the dynamic check, but that would happen a bit earlier. For example:

```
class BytePoint:
  _bytes /ByteArray  // Must be of size 2.

  // Allocates a fresh byte array.
  constructor: _bytes = ByteArray 2

  // Takes an array as argument and uses that one instead.
  constructor ._bytes: if _bytes.size != 2: throw "BAD ARGUMENTS"

  x -> int: return _bytes[0]
  x= new_x/int: _bytes[0] = new_x

  y -> int: return _bytes[1]
  y= new_y/int: _bytes[1] = new_y
```